# How to do authentication in react native using azure active directory b2c?

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've found no library for Azure Active Directory/ADAL for React Native. Could anyone give me a hint how to go about implementing ADAL with React Native?

Comment: ADAL is being deprecated in favour of MSAL. You should rather use the MSAL library.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration

Comment: @rbrayb.  MSAL is for the browser, not react native, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score -2):

**Use the  [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to integrate Azure AD B2C with your application.**

Microsoft also recommends customers use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to integrate Azure AD B2C. For more details, please refer  this document:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview.

To know how to implement you can refer  this git hub documents

[react-msal-sample](https://github.com/sunilbandla/react-msal-sample) and [MSAL Azure AD B2C sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)

Comment: Actually, I have already integrated it in React App using @azure/msal-react but now I want to use this authentication in React Native and I am unable to find any SDK or package to integrate it in React Native App. Could you please tell me a good NPM package for React Native?

Comment: Is this documents helps you  1)https://bilot.group/articles/authentication-with-azure-ad-using-msal-react-app/   2)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Clearly, this answer assumes react (web) and not react native, which is what the question is about.